# Dell Precision 5510 keeps muting microphone - Why?

Tags: microphone

I have a Dell Precision 5510. For whatever reason, any microphone that I have tried including the 1 that is built in to the laptop, 2 different web camera's with Mic & a Logitech headset with mic, the laptop keeps muting whatever mic I try to use.

How do I correct this and get my mics to stay on? I have tried deleting and replacing drivers, that gets it to work for about 12 minutes and then it mutes it again. I have installed Malware Bytes and scan it everyday. Nothing I do seems to work. Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have another computer you can use to test the mics on?  Also, are you still running Windows 10, or did you install a different OS on the laptop?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, all 3 of the independent mics have been tried on other computers and they work fine on them. The internal mic, I have no way of trying it on another computer.

Comment: What program are you using that you discovered the problem?  Are you recording in Audacity (or the like), and noticing a fade out, or talking to others and they notify you of the audio issue?  I doubt it is the same problem, but I remember there being an audio option to have Windows auto-adjust volume.

Comment: This is just off the main sound, right  click on the speaker, choose the recording tab, select any mic that is hooked up to the lap top, and then with in a few seconds of being on it mutes by itself. I use Zoom for Web Demos of our product and I would rather not have to wear a headset especially when we are in a video conference.